# how to check if Xen support hardware virtualization?

Tags: command-line, virtualization, xen

I am try to check if xen in ubuntu 18.04 support virtualization.
By following this comand:

```
$ xm info | grep caps
```

I am follow step 5 of this tutorial: 
[Check virtualization capabilities](https://trueconf.com/blog/knowledge-base/configure-xen-hypervisor-ubuntu-server-14-4-05.html)

The output of this command in my pc is:

```
eda-2@eda2-ThinkCentre-M82:~$ xm info | grep caps
ERROR:  A different toolstack (xl) have been selected!
```

What does mean? what i should to to check virtualization capabilities?
Pls help me, I am beginner in ubuntu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old command on a newer system. Please don't use instruction for a server 14.04 when you use 18.04.

xl is the default toolstack and as the error shows you need to us

```
xl
```

and not `xm`.

---

Not entirly true:  better is to check what

```
/etc/default/xen
```

is set to. It probably is `xl`.

Comment: I run this command:                                                                         etc/default/xen eda-2@eda2-ThinkCentre-M82:~$ sudo xl info                       the output is: xen_caps               : xen-3.0-x86_64 xen-3.0-x86_32p                          What does this mean?